# unsigned bit fields overflow

Tags: c++, bit-fields

Suppose we have a continuous process where we increment an unsigned char `+1` or `-1` and we want it to always stay in a range between `0 , 2^n - 1`,lets say for example that this range is `0 , 15`, I know that it is possible to do something like this:

```
unsigned char offset = 0;

while( condition )
{
    if(something)
    {
       offset += 1;
    }else
    {
       offset -= 1;
    }
    offset %= 16;
}
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to the same thing with bit fields, and whether it had any benefits:

```
unsigned char offset : 4;
offset = 0;

while( condition )
{
    if(something)
    {
       offset += 1;
    }else
    {
       offset -= 1;
    }
}
```

I am asking because if I understand it correctly, the first version will perform the `%` at every loop iteration, while the second will only do it ( if what I read is correct) when `offset` tries to overflow.

Comment: Arithmetic over- and under-flow of unsigned integers is well-defined. When you over- or under-flow an unsigned integer it will roll over. For example if you have `unsigned short v;` then `v = 65535; ++v;` will make `v` zero. And `v = 0; --v` will turn `v` into `65535`.

Comment: Right. There is no *unsigned overflow*, when you reach the max for the unsigned type, it will be reduced modulo back to 0.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah I understand that, my question was whether it is correct to assume that the second version is safe and faster  due to less `%` calls?

Comment: That I can't give you a yes/no on without going back to the standard and reading the bitfield section again on structs -- there are a few limitation that apply directly to bitfields -- and I have this nagging feeling that a bitfield cannot be treated as a type for this purpose. It's type is `unsigned char` so if you are expecting the 4-bits carved out by it to behave as a full type -- I don't think it does for this purpose.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.2.6 Representations of types(p4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p4) specifically excludes the word "type" when describing the m:bits that make up a bit-field. So jury is still out on that one...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits", whatever that means.

Comment: Safe? Yes. Faster? Who knows, depends on a zillion factors. If you want to squeeze the last bit of performance out of your code, asking stackoverflow won't help you, you need to actually measure and compare versions of *your* program in *your* environment.

Comment: In C, according to how bitfields are defined in the spec, the answer to the OP's question about whether overflow results in modulo-reduction is: yes. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908300/overflow-in-bit-fields). Is there any reason to suspect that this is not also the case in C++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overflow in bit fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908300/overflow-in-bit-fields)