# Bit width of a class

Tags: c++, bitset

there is a class declared as:

```
class Payload {
    uint8_t m_a : 1;
    uint8_t m_b : 5;
    uint8_t m_c : 2;
    uint8_t m_d : 4;
};
```

you see, the `sizeof(Payload) == 2`. So far so good. The total amount of bits is 12, it exceeds the 8bit thus 2Bytes are occupied.

**But is there a way how to get the amount of bits the class declares? I mean to return '12'...?** Sure to make the algorithm working for any kind of class definining bitfields as above, theoreticaly of any size...

Comment: I don't think so... (until reflection maybe).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That' s pretty clear but I was not asking for how many Bytes it occupies, thus sizeof( Payload ) but the amount of BITS - to programatically detect the bitwidth, the 12 in this particular example

Comment: Why do you need to know that the number of bits is 12 (assuming that's what you mean)?  Sounds like an xy problem.

Comment: I don't think we can know regular bytes padding currently, so bits padding...

Comment: Most processors access data in bytes. For this reason also C and C++ measure structures in bytes (actually chars).

Comment: @G.M. I am implementing a tagged_ptr, which uses the 'unused bits' thanks ot pointer alignment to store a payload. I can calculate how many bits are effectively unused by the pointer itself, e.g. allignment=1024, n_bits=10 etc and I wan to check whether my payload class with its 'bits' fits to the dimension of free to use bits of the aligned pointer, you know...

Comment: @MartinKopecký A type with bitfield members is considered to consume all bits of the bytes it occupies even padding bits. It is not possible to determine which of its bits are unused.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : Sure but can the 'active' bits be counted somehow?

Comment: @MartinKopecký No. C++ doesn't support what your trying to do.

Comment: Maybe you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908300/overflow-in-bit-fields and compute the size based on maximal values that can be stored within the class members?

Comment: @MartinPerry How overflowing for bitfields works is implementation defined, even for `unsigned` integer types. So you cannot rely on that. Maybe it works in C, but it does not in C++.

Comment: So maybe this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194009/size-of-a-bitfield-member. But again, may depends on compiler, so not entirely "portable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in a standard-conformant way.

[[class.bit]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.bit#1):

> the bit-field attribute is not part of the  type of the class member

which means this information cannot be extracted at compile time. Any kind of attempt to find this information using runtime introspection techniques would rely on, at best, implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even if this answer is not what I have hoped for...

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(Payload)*CHAR_BIT`. This gets the size of the structure in bytes and multiplies it by the number of bits per byte (it’s technically not always 8). This works because bitfield-containing structs cannot have a size in bits which is not a multiple of `CHAR_BIT`. The compiler will add padding bits after the last member.